# Lots of copies of the same button opening dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I've been working with JQuery lately for the first time and encountered problem. I have lots of copies of the same anchor which opens a dialog, the problem is when i click on anyone of them, the dialog opens in as many copies as there are anchors.

The code looks like this

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div#dialogbox').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#opener').click(function(){
        $('div#dialogbox').dialog('open);
    });

});
```

Dialog:

```
<div id="dialogbox">
    <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
```

Anchor:

```
<a href="#" id="opener">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: if I ready your question correctly then you have multiple `<a href="#" id="opener">Click Me</a>` which would be invalid html. Id's should be unique

Comment: just an observation but is there a closing bracket missing from .dialog('open); should be .dialog('open'); no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try

```
var popup;
$(document).ready(function(){
popup =  $('div#dialogbox').dialog({
autoOpen: false});
$('.opener').click(function(){ popup.dialog('open); });
});
```

if that solves your problem then you will want to follow some best practice with the var but just something quick to see if that solves the issue

would also follow other advice in other answer and change from id to class, note sure if that is your problem but you shouldn't have multiple id's with the same value

```
<a href="#" class="opener">Click Me</a>
```

Also lets be sure you only have one copy of the pop up on the page

Comment: No difference, still opening a lot of dialog boxes.

Comment: @jogproof just to be sure, there is only one DIV dialogbox on the page right? not one for each link?

Comment: Anyone handing prizes in stupidity contest? I had my dialogbox div in "for" loop...thanks ; )

Comment: @jogproof, glad to help. still should follow the other advice for the names to classes and i wouldn't mind if you mark this as answered ;) Code ON

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing it with something like this

```
<a href="#" class="opener">Click Me</a>
```

and your JS to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var popup = $('div#dialogbox').dialog({autoOpen: false});

    $('.opener').click(function(){
        popup.dialog('open);
    });
});
```

You're only meant to have 1 ID on the page of the same name, if you need multiple then you should be using a class.

Comment: I've done the changes you suggested and it still behaves in the same way.

Comment: As a suggestion, you can always format it like this if you want multiple different Modals -> http://jsfiddle.net/aekc4j5b/1/